# Download a presentation created by Adobe Presenter

Tags: adobe-flash

I am trying to download Adobe Presenter presentations so I can watch while I am disconnected from the internet. It's seems there's a way to download the source slides in a SWF format and the audio in mp3 format and puzzle the files back together. But are there any better/easier ways to do this?

I read that you can now download the presentations in an mp4 video format, unfortunately there were no instructions included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are watching the presentation in the browser, you might try to save the
entire webpage using the browser's *Save As* menu command for saving
the entire complete page. Different browsers have different save methods
and formats, so better try more than one.
Depending on the format of the webpage, the saved version might still be
functional offline.

Another solution might be to record the presentation on your screen as video
while it is playing.

Some screen-recording products are:

- [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/), free and open-source.
  This is perhaps the best-known and extensive screen-recording product, although
  it may require some fiddling because of the large number of available options.
  For a tutorial see the article
  [How to record screen with voice using Sharex](https://sublimelms.com/docs/Video-App-Guide/Video%20App/How_to_record_screen_with_voice_using_Sharex_.html).
- Some other free products can be found in the article
  [Best Free Screen Session Recorder](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-screen-session-recorder.htm).
  The listed products are reviewed with their weak and strong points, and the comments
  below the article are also useful.
  Some of the products are ActivePresenter and FlashBack Express.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @harrymc. I was hoping for a solution that where I can just download the presentation without having to record it first.

Comment: The browser's Save As menu command is your only other chance.

Comment: Sometimes you have to settle for less than you wish for.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so :)

Answer (score 1):

It will be difficult to get a MP4 file of a online presentation.

However, there is a way to publish Adobe Presenter projects as a MP4 video with Adobe Presenter Video Express. See https://helpx.adobe.com/presenter/using/publishing-video.html

Comment: Thanks for your post. The instructions are only for creating a MP4 version of a presentation that you are the owner of. However, I am trying to download a presentation that someone else created with sounds, so I can watch it without having to connect to the internet.